# pymongo insert only does not exist

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I used InsertOne() for bulk insert.

```
user1 = InsertOne({"user_id": 1})
user2 = InsertOne({"user_id": 2})
collection.bulk_write([user1, user2])
```

If `user_id = 1` already exist in collection, it throw `batch op errors occurred` errors.

I wonder that is there any method for only insert if data doesn't exist?

(Can't using get data and compare if data exist because I'm using `bulk_write`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is :  Use `ReplaceOne` with `upsert:true`. So that if the document already exists update wont have any effect, and if it doesn't exist, it will create the new document.

Try this:

```
user1 = ReplaceOne({"user_id": 1},{"user_id": 1},upsert = True)
user2 = ReplaceOne({"user_id": 2},{"user_id": 2},upsert = True)
collection.bulk_write([user1, user2])
```

Make sure you pass all the data you need to store in the `User` document, in the second argument of `ReplaceOne`

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer if it worked for you, so that it help others as well who might be facing the same/similar issue.

Comment: upsert usage is `ReplaceOne({'w': 1}, {'z': 1}, upsert=True)`. Anyway, Thanks :)

Comment: oh yea, i mixed it with javascript syntax by mistake. I will edit my answer to reflect the correct syntax.

Comment: I found problem. If there is no matched data, it throw `pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError: batch op errors occurred` exception. But I have to ignore it and go through again.

Comment: Solved. Just add `ordered=False` to `bulk_write()`. It will report errors after all commands executed.

Comment: Sounds like a good approach, But usually it is not advised to keep going on even after encountering an error, Thats why i didnt suggest it, but it suits your situation, so all good.